# is there any way to extract password protected zip file in cpanel?

Tags: cpanel

I am upload 100 GB zip file in my file server and zip file is password protected .

Is there any way to extract password protected zip file in my Cpanel ?

Comment: You can't do this with cpanel alone. Do you have root access? If not, you could try extracting it using a php script.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.

CPanel doesnt provide any feature to extract password protected archives

Visit this for more info https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-extract-zip-passworded-file.139473/